# schedule time interval of cron job in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I define a cron job which run every 1 minutes from 01:00 to 03:00 and from 10:00 to 12:00?

```
- description: mycronjob
  url: /runmycronjob/
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 01:00 to 03:00 and from 10:00 to 12:00
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [schedule format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#formatting_the_schedule) doesn't allow such combination. But you can easily do it from a combination of job schedules:

```
- description: mycronjob part 1
  url: /runmycronjob/
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 01:00 to 03:00

- description: mycronjob part 2
  url: /runmycronjob/
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 10:00 to 12:00
```